# PHP : Save value in array and sort the value to numerically desc?

Tags: php, sorting, loops

I want to save value from looping in an array. Then I want to sort it to numerically desc.

here is my code

```
<?php
$n = 5;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $n ; $i++){
$a = $i + 1;
echo $a;
} // the result is 1,2,3,4,5. How can I do sorting so the result will be 5,4,3,2,1?
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function desc($n){
    $arr = array();
    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $n ; $i++){
        array_push($arr,$i);
    }
    $arr = array_reverse($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo $value . " => ";
    }
}

desc(5); // output 5 => 4 => 3 => 2 => 1
```

PS. In this way you are saving values in array as well

Comment: dude, how if sorting the value without using array_reverse?? Can I use rsort()?

Comment: @VictoriaCho You can use `rsort` as well

Answer (score 1):

Simply flip the loop:

```
<?php
$n = 5;
// the for loop now starts at $n and will decrease $i by 1 after every loop
for ($i = $n ; $i > 0 ; $i--){
    echo $i;
} // the result is 5,4,3,2,1
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $array = array();
    $n = 5;
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $n ; $i++){
        array_push($array,($i+1));
    }

    $array = array_reverse($array);

    for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($array) ; $i++)
        echo $array[$i].'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: No, I have to save value from every loop in an array. then It has to desc the value from that array. Actually this is not my real case. I just try to make a simple question and solve my problem to save value in an array then descending it...

Comment: @VictoriaCho is this what you mean?